# Is there any API to get Train details of US Railway Service

Tags: php

Is there any API to get Train details of US Railway Service

Comment: You would have more luck looking into a web service then an API, as this could be implemented in many different programming languages.

Comment: @James Goodwin Huh? Since when can APIs not be implemented in many different programming language? The Twitter API, for example, is successfully used by just about every programming language in existence.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean passenger services. Nationally these are handled by Amtrak and locally by various transit authorities. Amtrak do not have an API as such, altho there's this discussion about screen scraping:

http://discuss.amtraktrains.com/index.php?/topic/32601-amtrakcom-api/

Basically there are web sites that do this but do it very infrequently.

Transit authorities are going to be on an authority by authority basis. There isn't a central clearing house as with the UK.

For other railroads, these are freight operations and do not have published timetables. Even route information can be hard to find (ie. Easier to extract from a map source offline)