# How to Grab Amtrak Scheduled/Estimated Data for a Given Train/Station?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, fetch, windows-8.1

Due to the nature of my commuter Amtrak train back home being late 10-20 minutes late the past few days, I want to develop a Windows 8 Metro/Desktop app that will notify someone given a train number and station what the status of the train is at a specified time so they know if they can clock in a few more minutes at work or not. Even though I've never done Windows 8 app dev (although I have done some dev in C#), toast notifications are well documented (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/toast-notifications-sample-52eeba29). However, I can't find anything concerning Amtrak data.

I know there has to be some sort of general methodology to fetch the scheduled and estimated arrival/departure data as their Android app has this feature. How do I pull this data using C# so I can put it into the app's variables?

Comment: You would need to have access to the Amtrak API/web service to get real time info, but I don't think they've made it public. There's also web scraping, but that might get you in trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537240/is-there-any-api-to-get-train-details-of-us-railway-service is a related (closed) question that basically asks the same thing.

Comment: Why would I get in trouble?

Comment: In their site's [Terms of use](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?c=Page&pagename=am%2FLayout&cid=1241305463068), it explicitly prohibits the "Use [of] any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application or other manual or automatic device or process to retrieve, index, “data mine” or in any way reproduce or circumvent the navigational structure or presentation of the Site or its contents"